# Sorting custom table view cells in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, user-interface

I am working on an small project where I have an app that takes in tvshow information entered by the user and displays it in a custom tableview cell. I would like to sort the shows as they are entered based on which current episode the user is on. I know this code works because I tested it with print statements and it sorts the array but it does not sort on the simulator. So I just was curious where I should place this so that it sorts on the app side.

```
  func sortShows() {
        let sortedShows = tvShows.sorted { $0.currentEpisode > $1.currentEpisode}
        TVShowTableView.reloadData()
           print(sortedShows)
       }
```

Here is where I am currently placing it inside my view controller

```
extension TVShowListViewController: AddTVShowDelegate {
    func tvShowWasCreated(tvShow: TVShow) {
        tvShows.append(tvShow)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        TVShowTableView.reloadData()
        sortShows()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `TVShowTableView` the *instance* of your table view? Or is the *class*? Instances (vars) should start with lower-case to help keep it straight. If it *is* the instance / var, try taking out `TVShowTableView.reloadData()` in your `tvShowWasCreated()` func, since you are also calling that after you've done your sort.

Comment: Yes it is the instance of my tableView and I removed the extra .reloadData, I also changed the casing on my tableview instance.

Comment: Did that fix your issue?

Comment: No it did not, the cells still don't update after each new show is added. Only in the compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part of your code:

```
func sortShows() {
    // here you are creating a NEW array
    let sortedShows = tvShows.sorted { $0.currentEpisode > $1.currentEpisode}
    // here you tell the table view to reload with the OLD array
    TVShowTableView.reloadData()
    print(sortedShows)
}
```

In your controller class, you probably have something like:

```
var tvShows: [TVShow] = [TVShow]()
```

and then you populate it with shows, like you do with a new show:

```
tvShows.append(tvShow)
```

Then your controller is doing something like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tvShowCell", for: indexPath) as! TVShowCell
    cell.tvShow = tvShows[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

What you want to do is add another var to your class:

```
var sortedShows: [TVShow] = [TVShow]()
```

then change your sort func to use that array:

```
func sortShows() {
    // use the existing class-level array
    sortedShows = tvShows.sorted { $0.currentEpisode > $1.currentEpisode}
    // here you tell the table view to reload
    TVShowTableView.reloadData()
    print(sortedShows)
}
```

and change your other funcs to use the `sortedShows` array:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // use sortedShows array
    return sortedShows.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tvShowCell", for: indexPath) as! TVShowCell
    // use sortedShows array
    cell.tvShow = sortedShows[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

and you'll want to call `sortShows()` at the end of `viewDidLoad()` (or wherever you are getting your initial list of shows).

**Edit**

Another way you might use `cellForRowAt`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tvShowCell", for: indexPath) as! TVShowCell

    // use sortedShows array
    let tvShow = sortedShows[indexPath.row]
    cell.showTitleLable.text = tvShow.title
    cell.showDecriptionLable.text = tvShow.description

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I have something very different in my cellForRowAt because I am passing three text fields into my tableview cell

Comment: @RichGibbs - it doesn't matter. The point is that you need to use your ***sorted array*** for your data, not your un-sorted array. See the **Edit** at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Thank you. That second edit was closer to what I had so that made it work!! Thank you!!